# Python 2.7 regular expression match issue

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Suppose I am using the following regular expression to match, logically the regular expression means match anything with prefix `foo:` and ends with **anything** which is not a space. Match group will be the parts exclude prefix `foo`

My question is what exactly means **anything** in Python 2.7? Any ASCII or? If anyone could share some document, it will be great. Thanks.

```
a = re.compile('foo:([^ ]+)')
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: It means exactly what you wrote: **Anything** that is **not** a space.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, thanks for the answer and vote up. My question is actually what is **Anything** here, is there a character table for **Anything** in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression metacharacter which matches any character is `.` (dot).

```
a = re.compile('foo:(.+)')
```

The character class `[^ ]` matches any one character which isn't one of the characters between the square brackets (a literal space, in this example).  The quantifier `+` specifies one or more repetitions of the preceding expression.

Comment: Thanks tripleee, vote up. The regular expression I posted will match anything but not a space, and my question is more about what means **anything** here. **Anything** could be any characters, UTF-8, unicode, space, non-printable character, as long as they are represented by Python 2.7 `str`, etc.? Is there a definition what exactly means **anything**?

Comment: Repeat: `.` matches any one character (Unicode character, in modern Python) and `[^ ]` matches any one character except space.  The repetition means match as many matches as possible of the same expression.

Comment: Thanks tripleee, vote up and mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
a = re.compile('foo:\S*')
```

\S means anything but whitespace.

I recommend you check out http://pythex.org. 
It's really good for testing out regular expresions and has a decent cheat-sheet.

**UPDATE:**

Anything (.) matches anything, all unicode/UTF-8 characters.

Comment: boogiehound, thanks for the answer and vote up. My question is actually what is **Anything** here, is there a character table for **Anything** in Python 2.7?

Comment: The cheat sheet on the linked site has that, too.

Comment: I am 99% sure, anything means anything. No character table needed. I never had any Problem with any characters not matching 'anything'

Comment: @boogiehound, thanks and vote up. Confused what do you mean `.`? In my original regular expression, there is no `.`?

Comment: @Vaelor, thanks for the reply and vote up. For anything, you mean any characters, UTF-8, unicode, space, non-printable character, as long as they are represented by Python 2.7 `str`, etc.?

Comment: @LinMa the dot (.) symbol in regexes matches any character. See the cheat sheet in the link.

Comment: Good reference, thanks boogiehound, vote up for your reply.